# Default values for the arguments to a Unix shell script?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, scripting

Normally when a parameter is passed to a shell script, the value goes into ${1} for the first parameter, ${2} for the second, etc.

How can I set the default values for these parameters, so that if no parameter is passed to the script, we can use a default value for ${1}?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't, but you can assign to a local variable like this: `${parameter:-word}` or use the same construct in the place you need $1.  this menas use *word* if _paramater is null or unset

Note, this works in *bash*, check your shell for the syntax of *default values*

Comment: It also works in Bourne, Korn and POSIX shells, so it is widely usable.  It does not work in C Shell derivatives, but then, sea shells are best left on the sea shore.

Comment: If an empty string can be a valid input, you have to use `${parameter-word}` - It will not clobber empty strings.

Answer (score 11):

You could consider:

```
set -- "${1:-'default for 1'}" "${2:-'default 2'}" "${3:-'default 3'}"
```

The rest of the script can use `$1`, `$2`, `$3` without further checking.

Note: this does not work well if you can have an indeterminate list of files at the end of your arguments; it works well when you can have only zero to three arguments.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_PARAM=${1:-default}

echo $MY_PARAM
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I don't understand your question well, yet I would feel inclined to solve the problem in a less sophisticated manner:

```
                     ! [[ ${1} ]]   &&   declare $1="DEFAULT"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If `$1` is not set, the name in `declare $1="DEFAULT"` is empty, which is not going to help.  If it is set (for example, the script was invoked as `./script abc`), then the `declare` you suggest makes the variable `abc` equal to `DEFAULT` without touching `$1`.  You simply cannot set 'positional parameters' (`$1`, `$2`, etc) that way.